# Getting React.createElement: type is invalid when replacing component in select-react

Tags: reactjs, es6-class, react-select

I am using `es6` classes and `react-select` to create a dropdown menu and want to replace the component for the `react-select` menu icon. My methods are static, so I expect to be able to use them by calling them using the class name, in this case `CustomSelectDropDown`, but I keep getting this error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: . Did you accidentally export a JSX literal
>   instead of a component?
>           in Select (created by StateManager)

My code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCaretDown } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
library.add(faCaretDown);

export class CustomSelectDropDown extends Component {
    static Placeholder(props) {
        return <components.Placeholder {...props} />;
    }

    static CaretDownIcon () {
        return <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-down" />;
    };

    static DropdownIndicator(props) {
        return (
            <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
                { this.CaretDownIcon() }
            </components.DropdownIndicator>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="customSelect" id={this.props.idName}>
                <div className="fb--w60">
                    <Select 
                        ...
                        components={{ 
                            Placeholder: CustomSelectDropDown.Placeholder(), 
                            DropdownIndicator: CustomSelectDropDown.DropdownIndicator() }}
                        ...
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomSelectDropDown;
```

What I am doing incorrectly? I thought this was the [proper way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#From_class_constructor_and_other_methods) of using `static` methods.

If I try to change the `DropdownIndicator`'s call `this.CaretDownIcon()` to `CustomSelectDropDown.CaretDownIcon()` instead, then I get the following a different error, shown below, but I think using `this.CaretDownIcon()` should be the right way.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.
>      Check the render method of `Select`.

Perhaps this has to do more with `react-select` than `JS/reactjs/es6`?

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know that your components there need to be `static` methods. They don't need to be properties of your component, they just need to be available to the class itself. You might even want them defined outside of your `class` definition all together, so that they aren't publicly accessible in any way.

```
const CaretDownIcon = () => <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-down" />;

// ...other definitions

export class CustomSelectDropDown extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    // ... getting whatever prop and state values you need
    return (
      <Select
        {...otherProps}
        components={{
          Placeholder: MyPlaceholder,
          // ... etc, etc
        }}
```

Second, in your `CustomDropdownIndicator`, you're trying to insert a React component using a method, when all you have to do is put in the tag.

```
const CustomDropdownIndicator = (props) => (
  <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
    <CaretDownIcon />
  </components.DropdownIndicator>
);
```

I don't think your issue was in how to call a static method. `ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod()` or `this.constructor.staticMethod()` is the right syntax. I think your issue was you were trying to invoke the method, in the `components` config, rather than simply passing those stateless components in to the config.

```
<Select 
  ...
  components={{ 
    Placeholder: CustomSelectDropDown.Placeholder, 
    DropdownIndicator: CustomSelectDropDown.DropdownIndicator 
  }}
  ...
/>
```

That said, static methods can be called on the class without having an instance of the class, so the question again becomes "Should this really be a `static` method? Or are these bits only necessary within my class?"

Comment: thanks @Steve, I believe these functions are actually stateless components, so I solved my issue by moving them into their own files, and import them as components. What I don't understand is why using `static` keyword for the functions causes issues. I mean, I should be able to call them `ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod()`, but this did not work. I defining my `CaretDownIcon` as a component, even thought it does in fact only return the icon.